# solution to an ODE separable variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have this ODE: $du/u = dt$ which I think the solution is $\ln|u| = t + c \leftrightarrow |u| = e^{t+c} = ce^t$. Is this correct? Is $u$ really a function then, since each value of $t$ would be mapped onto two values of $u$?

Comment: $u=e^{c+t}=ce^t$ is correct.

Comment: $|u|=ce^t$ is true provided $c\ge0$, but we know more: $u=ce^t$, and $c$ can be negative.

Comment: The solution of an ODE isn't always an explicit function $u=f(t)$. Most ODEs have implicitely defined solutions $F(t,u)=0$, i.e. a relation where we can't write $u$ explicitely as a function of $t$, and there can be more than one value of $u$ for a given $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps 
$$ \frac{1}{u}du=dt $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{u}du=\int dt $$
$$ \ln |u|+C_1=t +C_2 $$
$$ \ln |u|=t +C_2 -C_1=t+C $$
$$ e^{\ln |u|}=e^{t+C} $$
$$ u=e^{t+C} $$
Note that the domain of $\frac{1}{u}$ is $\{u\in\mathbb{R}:u\ne 0\}$, which includes negative numbers. Also the domain of $\ln u$ is $\{u\in\mathbb{R}:u\gt 0\}$, which does not include negative numbers. This is why when we integrate $\frac{1}{u}$, we get $\ln|u|+C$. Once we get rid of the $\ln|u|$, we can also get rid of the absolute value bars because $u$ in this case, is allowed to be negative.